# Direction of Friction in accelerated rolling motion

Tags: rotational-dynamics, friction

If we want to find the formula  of friction force in the case of pure rolling motion. Suppose F force act on top most point

First of all translation equation is

$$F-f=ma$$

Where f is friction force and for rolling motion equation is

$$FR+fR=I\alpha$$

Where I is moment of inertia By solving this two equation we will get

$$f=(mRh-I)F/(MR^2+I)$$

But in my equation number 2 for rolling motion friction will act rightward so we have to make this equation

$$FR-fR=I\alpha$$

It means in second equation direction of friction chosen is left but actually direction according to moving the case of rolling is rightward

Please solve my Direction doubt.

Comment: well actually there is a sort of trick to  check the direction  of friction force. If the ext. Force applied is below the center of rotation or the axle (for a disc) then the friction will be in **left direction**.  If the force is upward then two cases arise.. and depending on the position of that force decides the **direction of friction (which could be left or right)**.

Comment: What is $h$ supposed to be?

Comment: pl. check this free [textbook](https://cnx.org/contents/MymQBhVV@175.4:ERqcxYN2/Role-of-friction-in-rolling#:~:text=Accelerated%20rolling%20motion%20and%20friction%20Torques%20causes%20acceleration%20in%20forward%20direction.&text=The%20friction%20between%20the%20wheel,in%20the%20right%20figure%20above.) It should clear all your doubts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't define it, but I am guessing $h$ is the distance between the center of the object and where the force $F$ is applied above the center.

Your work is correct; you end up with the following expression for the friction force:

$$f=\frac{mRh-I}{mR^2+I}F$$

It looks like the issue you are having is that the numerator $mRh-I$ can be either positive or negative depending on the values of $mRh$ and $I$. Let's cover this conceptual confusion.

Because your equations were set up assuming friction was acting to the left, a positive value of $f$ means that friction indeed does act to the left, and a negative value of $f$ means that we had the direction wrong in the beginning, so friction would be acting to the right.

So when $mRh>I$, we have friction acting to the left. When $mRh<I$, we have friction acting to the right. In the case where $mRh=I$, we actually would require no friction at all to have rolling without slipping. This would be the case if, for example, we applied $F$ to the edge of a thin hoop.